# Sitting to Standing Posture Transition Accelerometer Triaxial Data Explanation

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, sensor

I don't have a physics background. (I'm a Computer Science student)

I have a waist-worn accelerometer provided by the school which is quite reliable. I've captured data of sitting still to standing still transitions from a person. Here is the result synchronised from many tests, the orange curve depicts data from the vertical axis. 
[image]

Could anybody please explain to me the pattern of acceleration data?
Why does the acceleration's magnitude always increase first before decreasing? (The sign of value depends on the device's configuration so you don't need to worry about it)
Should it not be the other way around?

As far as I know about physics, Newton's 2nd Law states $F = m . a$ so I would think that when the person stands up, a force in the upwards direction is created which is opposite the the Earth gravitational force which heads down so the resulting force must be lower than the original force (which only includes the Earth gravitational force) leading to a reduction in the acceleration?

Also if possible could you let me know what possibly causes the sudden drop in acceleration right after that?

Many thanks.

Comment: "Why does the acceleration always increase first before decreasing?" Why do you think it does? It looks like decrease first exactly half the time.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast The question is in terms of magnitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accelerometers on the Space Station, or on any other orbiting spacecraft, report an acceleration of nearly zero in all three axes except when the spacecraft is firing its thrusters. Accelerometers do not sense gravitation.

When an accelerometer is at rest with respect to the surface of the Earth, the forces acting on the accelerometer are gravitation pulling it Earthward and an upward force (typically the normal force) that keeps the accelerometer from falling Earthward. While the accelerometer doesn't sense gravitation, it does sense that upward force. Your accelerometer's output is in units of gees. You see an acceleration of -1 *g* on the second component of the accelerometer's output. This direction is "up".

To start moving in some direction, the net force on the accelerometer must necessarily be non-zero, at least momentarily. When you stand up from a sitting position, your waist initially accelerates upward and forward. The acceleration that the accelerometer can sense are an upward component that exceeds greater than one *g* and a horizontal acceleration forward. This is exactly what your accelerometer registers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That explains the increase in magnitude. But then why does the acceleration magnitude drop to lower than 1g right after that? Does this mean the upward component is momentarily lower than 1g at that point? If so what could possibly cause that? All I could think of is that it's probably because the accelerometer orientation momentarily changes when we stands up which makes the vertical axis tilt a little bit leading to a drop in magnitude, then when the body comes to rest at standing posture the orientation is restored making the reading back again -1g? Is that possible?

Comment: @DanhThanhNguyen - If you tilt your upper body forward as you start to stand up, you will temporarily rotate the accelerometer so that is no longer oriented with one axis vertical. The sensed acceleration due to the normal force is instead spread across multiple axes.